# Wordpress 3.7.1 Taxonomy Template Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

I am having an issue with a taxonomy template. It worked before I upgraded Wordpress to 3.7.1, I was wondering if there is an issue with the taxonomy pages when upgrading wordpress.

The template I am using for the taxonomy page is taxonomy-watch-brands.php

```
query_posts(array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'sold',
    'post_type' => 'watches',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'watch-brands',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $make
        ),
    )
));
```

To summarise, its seems since upgrading Wordpress the taxonomy template is not being picked up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `query_posts()` shouldn't be used -- use `WP_Query` instead.  See here for more -- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/16121 .

Comment: Also: is the template not loading, or is it loading but not returning any posts?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The template is not loading, for some reason it is going to the attachment page. But before the upgrade it use to load the template.